# Ending of scroll event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, scroll

Suppose I have a huge list of photos and I want to display it 20 by 20  in fix `auto-scrolled area`, and each time I get to the bottom of the list (end of the scroll).

I want the next 20 photos to be loaded (as for the mobile when you want to reload your tweets or fb' posts).

I suppose I will use an `Ajax` post request as soon as I reached the end of the scroll but how to detect the event.

Is there any reference to do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? Essentially you listen out for the `scroll` event, and check the `scrollHeight` of the element. You could always look at the following jQuery plugin > http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: use `Jquery.scrollTop()` calculate with window height and trigger your function refer http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds as though you're looking for an infinite scroll script (although your question is somewhat ambigious). Anyway, why reinvent the wheel? This jQuery plugin does exactly what you're looking for:

[Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)